# How to make a editor just output part of datas(eclipse plugin development)

Tags: eclipse, plugins, text-editor

I have some structured item want to show by editor, for example, the item's structure may like this {1,"hello"}, the "1" identity this item and the "hello" is item's content. now i want just show item's content to user, but the editor should know the item's identity, then, when one user select the content of an item, the editor should pass the item's identity to me, so i could know which item the user selected clearly(because the identity's function is just to distinguish items, so it should not be output to disturb users).

Any sugesstion is appreciated!

Comment: So, do you want a text editor or some your editor is based on a list, table or tree?

Comment: all is ok, just care if it can implement my requirment

Comment: This seems strange to me, because you are implementing the editor, so you can make it do anything you want :) In case of tree viewer and so, Zoltan already explained the basics. Its JFace viewers 101. In case of text, it's different. Will this text be editable or readonly. The API there is more complex. So, which case you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can base your editor on a JFace viewer, where the viewers input (set by the setInput() method) is the collection of items you presented.

The content provider traverses this collection, and returns the correct items; finally the labelprovider returns only the content of the item.

Comment: i will try, but can it support when user just select an itme's content in the editor, the editor can pass the item's id to me?

Comment: More specifically, the selection of the JFace viewer will become the exact Object your content provider returned.